# is it possible to define execution order for a set of threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

My understanding is that threads in theory are executed in parallel. JVM decides; when a resource is available which thread to pick from the waiting thread queue (based on some algorithm).

Hence we can not provide/enforce a sequence of execution for threads.

Say my java application has 3 threads, t1, t2 and t3.

For some specific reason; I want the threads to execute in this order:
t3 then t1 and then t2.

Is it possible to do this? Does java provided any way of doing this?

Comment: Can you edit your post to explain _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: If you want sequential execution, then why are you using threads?

Comment: Yes - the best approach is to put the code from the three threads onto a single one.

Comment: @Gary it does not have a practical background from anything I am working on right now. I was refreshing my understanding and this question came up in my mind.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth thank you. so executing threads in sequence is a technical oxymoron. Like extending a final class in java. So the very idea of sequencing threads is against the design itself. Actually so far in any literature I have come across; none spelled this out in a more precise and strict manner.

Comment: @Ayusman Well, no. There's no way to extend a final class, but with the right synchronization and latches, you could execute threads in sequence. It would look something like: `ThreadA: work(); latchB.countDown();` + `ThreadB: latchB.await(); moreWork(); latchC.countDown();` etc. But using multiple threads to emulate single-threaded behavior is a bit... weird. So it's not a technical oxymoron, it's just way too complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Executor:

```
executor.execute(runnable1);
wait();
executor.execute(runnable2);
wait();
executor.execute(runnable3);
wait();
```

And of course, each Runnable has to end with a `notify()` statement.

Comment: Sorry, missed the `notify()` comment.

Comment: If you mean it's not really the best way to do it, I agree totally. In the meantime, I found an example of what Ayusman wanted to do, using Executor in a better way, in the Javadoc itself: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html The SerialExecutor seems to be pretty close to what was asked...

Comment: No, I meant that I had misread your answer.  I retract my -1 and comment.

Comment: If the runnable completes before the call to wait, the wait will not end.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tell the thread scheduler which order to execute threads in. If you need to ensure that a certain piece of code which is running on thread A must run before another piece of code running on thread B, you must enforce that order using locks or `wait()`/`notify()`.

For example, you could use a variable which was accessible to both threads as a "flag" to indicate whether it is safe for thread B to go ahead. Thread B could `wait()` in a loop, checking the value of that variable. Then when it was safe for thread B to run, thread A could set the variable and wake thread B up using `notify()`.

So yes, it is possible to enforce a desired order between things which happen on different threads. Generally, though, you want to avoid writing such low-level, detailed code. It is just too easy to get things wrong and cause subtle, hard-to-find bugs. When you are dealing with multithreaded code, *always* try to use high-level building blocks if you can.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use threads**, is the straightforward answer.

If you don't want code to run out of order, then why are you using threads at all?  Just execute things step by step like normal.

If you want certain *parts* of the threads to run in order, then use standard concurrency mechanisms like locks, wait/notify, and semaphores, but if you just want whole operations to run in a specific order, then...run them in order.  Without threads.

Answer (score 1):

Since java 8 this has become very easy using [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) :

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(runnable3)
            .thenRunAsync(runnable1)
            .thenRunAsync(runnable2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join a thread on another so he'll run when the other one finishes.

Answer (score 0):

### You can set order for your threads.

I've tried to modelling your situation:

```
public class ThreadJoinExample {
    private static final Thread FIRST = new Thread( new RunnableImpl(), "first" );
    private static final Thread SECOND = new Thread( new RunnableImpl(), "second" );
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //here have started current thread or "main" thread that will control above threads
        FIRST.start();
        //waiting 2 seconds, "stop" your current thread and after current thread will start this "t3" thread until it will dead
        try {
            FIRST.join(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SECOND.start();
        //"stop" your current thread immediately and run "t1" thread until it will dead.
        try {
            SECOND.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Or we can wait for all threads and in the end - finish current main thread
        try {
            FIRST.join();
            SECOND.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Current thread is going die");
    }
}
class RunnableImpl implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Started thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread is going die: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
Started thread: first
Started thread: second
Thread is going die: first
Thread is going die: second
Current thread is going die
```

**summary:** With **.join()** method we can move current thread to Runnable state until the time when "joined thread" will dead